# Extra text node in nodelist?

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist, htmlcollection, child-nodes

I have a section element having 3 div parent elements, I want to log section children.

```html
<section class="section1">
        <div class="parent">
            <p class="childP">hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <p class="childP">bro
        </div>
        <div class="parent-3">
            <p class="childP">bro
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
const section = document.querySelector('.section1');
```

when I log, `console.log(section.childNodes);` the output is `NodeList(7) [text, div.parent, text, div.parent, text, div.parent-3, text]`

What is this Extra text in node list ?

I tried `console.log(section.children)` is woking completely fine giving output in Element Nodes i.e HTMLcollection, I need the reason for extra text in `section.childNodes` node list?

Comment: It's the whitespace between `>` and `<div` - basically one newline and some spaces (or tabs)

Comment: As for why it was designed this way, HTML DOM was designed to preserve the document not just the **content**. By document the spec is referring to the HTML source code. The DOM API wanted to give developers the ability to recreate the entire HTML source code (including indentation) by simply parsing the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is for the whitespace between each of the child `<div>` elements. Here is the markup with the whitespace removed, and thus no `Text` nodes are present in `.childNodes`.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.section1').childNodes)
```

```html
<section class="section1"><div class="parent">
    <p class="childP">hello</p>
  </div><div class="parent">
    <p class="childP">bro
  </div><div class="parent-3">
    <p class="childP">bro
  </div></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`childNodes` will return any `element` or `text` or `comment` nodes whose direct children of the target element.

**So, the question is where do the text nodes come from?!**

The new lines between the `div`s element is considered as a text node.

If, you remove the new lines, there will be no text nodes.

```js
console.log([...document.querySelector('.section1').childNodes].map(e => e.nodeName))
```

```html
<section class="section1"><div class="parent"><p class="childP">hello</p></div><div class="parent"><p class="childP">bro</div><div class="parent-3"><p class="childP">bro</div></section>
```